# re-transmission of re-invite over UDP

Tags: sip

I have a scenario where my terminal receives re-invite from server and my terminal first responds with 100 trying and then sends 200 Ok and waits for ACK from server. But after sending 200 Ok ,my terminal receives  this re-invite again  .

So my question is what should be the response by my terminal .It should re-transmit the same 200 Ok or it should send 491 request pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be re-transmitting the same 200 OK response for any duplicate INVITE requests.

See the [SIP RFC 17.1.1.1 Overview of INVITE Transaction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.1.1.1) for teh details.

Comment: but this section doesn't answers my query specifically.Can you suggest some more information which is specific.Also can we ignore this re-transmitted invite ?

Comment: No you can't ignore it. The re-transmitted INVITE could have arrived because the previous 200 OK response did not get through. You must resend the original response any time you receive a duplicate SIP request. And yes nothing in the SIP RFC is particularly clear. You'll often have to read half a dozen different chapters to get the full picture about an aspect like this.